# AVFoundation Error Codes

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, avfoundation, avcapturephotosettings

I am getting following two error messages when taking RAW and also JPEG photos.  I have no way to diagnose these:

> Error capturing photo: Error Domain=AVFoundationError- Domain
>   Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"
>   Userlnfo={NSLocalizedFailur- eReason=An unknown erroroccurred (42686),
>   NSLocalizedDescription:The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingEr- ror=0x1c804bfa0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusError- Domain
>   Code=-12686 "(null)"}}

also...

> Error capturing photo: Error Domain=AVFoundationError-Domain
>   Code=-11800 The operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo.{NSLocalized-FailureReason=An unknown error occurred
>   (-16802), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingEr-ror=0x1c4243f30 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusError-Domain
>   Code=-16802 "(null)"}}

This seems to happen right after this function in **AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate**:

```
optional func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)
```

These seem to happen randomly upon repeated photo capturing.

**UPDATE**

RAW Setup

```
       func updatePhotoSettings () {
self.photoOutput.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([])

let newPhotoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: OSType(self.photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!),
                                                          processedFormat: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG])
            newPhotoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: self.photoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]]
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                newPhotoSettings.embeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat =  [AVVideoCodecKey: self.photoOutput.availablePhotoCodecTypes[0]]
            }
            newPhotoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
            newPhotoSettings.flashMode = self.flashMode
            newPhotoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = false
            newPhotoSettings.livePhotoMovieFileURL = nil
            self.photoOutput.photoSettingsForSceneMonitoring = newPhotoSettings

            self.photoOutput.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([newPhotoSettings])

}
```

Capture Call:

```
final func snapImage () {

            let photoCaptureDelegate = PhotoCaptureDelegate(with: self.photoOutput.preparedPhotoSettingsArray.first!,
                                       willCapturePhotoAnimation: {
                //Shutter animation
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                    self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.opacity = 0
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                        self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.opacity = 1
                    })
                }

            }, didCapturePhoto: {

                //Photo Saved animation

            }, completed:  { [unowned self] photoCaptureDelegate in
                self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureDelegate.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = nil
            })


            self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureDelegate.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = photoCaptureDelegate

            self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: self.photoOutput.preparedPhotoSettingsArray.first!, delegate: photoCaptureDelegate)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Goes to update photo settings for next shot
                self.updatePhotoSettings()
            }
        }
    }
```

Photo Capture Delegate

```
import AVFoundation
import Photos
import MobileCoreServices

class PhotoCaptureDelegate: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {


         private(set) var requestedPhotoSettings     : AVCapturePhotoSettings

         private let willCapturePhotoAnimation       : () -> ()
         private let didCapturePhoto                 : () -> ()
         private let completed                       : (PhotoCaptureDelegate) -> ()

         private var jpegPhotoData                   : Data?

         private var dngPhotoData                    : Data?


    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(with requestedPhotoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings,
        willCapturePhotoAnimation: @escaping () -> (),
        didCapturePhoto: @escaping () -> (),
        completed: @escaping (PhotoCaptureDelegate) -> ())
    {
        self.requestedPhotoSettings = requestedPhotoSettings
        self.willCapturePhotoAnimation = willCapturePhotoAnimation
        self.didCapturePhoto = didCapturePhoto
        self.completed = completed
    }


    private final func didFinish() {
        self.completed(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Will Capture
    final func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willCapturePhotoForResolvedSettings resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
        willCapturePhotoAnimation()
    }

    final func capture(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureForResolvedSettings resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {

    }


    // MARK: - iOS 11 Did Finish Photo
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    final func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

            if let error = error {

                PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Error processing photo: \(error)")
                self.didCapturePhoto()

            } else {

                if photo.isRawPhoto {
                    self.dngPhotoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
                    return

                } else {
                    if self.jpegPhotoData == nil {
                        self.jpegPhotoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
                        self.didCapturePhoto()
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
    }


    // MARK: - Did Finish Capture
    final func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Error capturing photo: \(error)")
            didFinish()
            return


        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {

                var temporaryDNGFileURL : URL? = nil
                self.dngPhotoData != nil {
                        temporaryDNGFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("\(resolvedSettings.uniqueID).dng"))
                        do {
                            try self.dngPhotoData!.write(to: temporaryDNGFileURL!, options: [.atomic])
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Could not write DNG Data: \(error)")
                            return
                        }
                }

                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
                    if (self.jpegPhotoData != nil) {

                        creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: self.jpegPhotoData!, options: nil)

                        if let temporaryDNGFileURL = temporaryDNGFileURL {

                            let companionDNGResourceOptions = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                            companionDNGResourceOptions.shouldMoveFile = true
                            creationRequest.addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, fileURL: temporaryDNGFileURL, options: companionDNGResourceOptions)

                        }
                    }
                }, completionHandler: { [unowned self] success, error in

                    if let error = error {
                        PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Error occurered while saving photo to photo library: \(error)")
                    }
                    if (temporaryDNGFileURL != nil) {
                        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: temporaryDNGFileURL!.path) {
                            do {
                                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: temporaryDNGFileURL!)
                            } catch let error as NSError {
                                PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Could not remove DNG File: \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })


            }

        else {
            PhotoCaptureDelegate.showError(sentMessage: "Not authorized to save photo")
            self.didFinish()
            return
        }

}



    private static func showError (sentMessage: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: sentMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert button title."), style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

### NOTES

1. Apple's AVCam Sample code was closely followed.
2. This crash happens ONLY after one of more successful photo captures.  Produced RAW file is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you show the code that sets up the capture session and takes the photo?

Comment: Updated original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You're calling `updatePhotoSettings()` before the image capture has finished which is causing errors. Try doing it from the completion handler or before you snap an image.

p.s. Really AVFoundation should've made this error harder to make or at least been clearer that this wouldn't work.

**previous, incorrect guesses**

You don't show how you configure the `AVCaptureSession` which is important,  but

1. if you enable `AVCapturePhotoSettings` `isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled`, you need to also enable `isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled` (might be `highResolutionCaptureEnabled` for you - what version of swift are you using?):

   ```
   self.photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
   ```
2. your `PhotoCaptureDelegate` looks like it's going out of scope, which won't help. Assign it to a member variable to prolong its life.
3. set a `.photo` preset on your `AVCaptureSession`

Comment: 1.I do enable self.photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true when I setup the session. 2.This seems to be very interesting.  If do this, this would go against Apple's sample code.  But will try.  so just have a weak reference to it? 3. I do have .photo for AVCaptureSession's Preset.

Comment: What sample code is that? I think you need to show some more code, like the session configuration and how you repeatedly capture - from what you've shown, calling `snapImage()` twice results in an exception with the message "[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] Settings may not be re-used".

Comment: For repeated capture, snapImage() is called repeatedly.  At the end of snapImage(), updatePhotoSettings () is called, where it will prep photo settings for next shot. I eliminated this  self.photoOutput.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray() being an issue, because if I take that out and just do the settings inside snapImage() just before capture, same issue remains.

Comment: Also, I think the most interesting fact here is, this crash only happens after one or more successful captures.  Files from successful ones seems to be fine and not corrupted.

Comment: Ah confused, `updatePhotoSettings()` is a recent edit. When is `updatePhotoSettings()` initially called?

Comment: Could the problem be that you're calling `updatePhotoSettings()` before the image capture has finished? Reconfiguring the `AVCapturePhotoOutput` while it's busy sounds like something that would cause unexpected errors.

Comment: What you stated last seemed to be true.  It looks like updatePhotoSettings() was being called before the capture was finished.  Could u update your answer? So I could check mark and add the bounty to it.

Comment: Done - I also see now that your delegate's scope is extended in `inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates`.